# cygwin + console2 ctrl-c keyboard interrupt not working

Tags: console, cygwin, console2

I'm using [console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console) as my shell for cygwin and control-C is not working.

I have made sure that control-C is not being used as a hotkey in my console2 settings.

This is how I run cygwin from console2
`D:\Programs\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i`

To check for yourself, do
`ping google.com -t` and try to interrupt it with control C.

Here is my console2 console.xml file, http://pastebin.com/mZ3yHe6D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in cygwin, it should be fixed in the upcoming cygwin release (1.7.17), see [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3553127&group_id=43764&atid=437332)

---

**Update:** 1.7.17 was released on Oct 20, 2012. The problem is indeed fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

So I was running into this issue through the Git Msys install (utilizes MingW32) on Windows too.

The problem was Ctrl + C was bound to the Copy Selection which negates the ability to pass the Ctrl + C interrupt into the actual console. Reassigning that hotkey binding allows you to actually use Ctrl + C again for interrupting server tasks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Console2, reassign the Hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to other, then the termination will work.
Thanks Silva

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reassigning the hotkeys you can also simply press `Ctrl-Shift-C` for keyboard interruption in Console2